# React-native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-native-navigation

I have created 2 Screens Screen1.js and Screen2.js
Screen1.js will be splashscreen  while Screen2.js will be  loginscreen.
What i want to do is to open Screen2.js 5 seconds after Screen1.js is render.
I tried to import {Navigation} from 'react-native' but it is not anymore on this library. Any idea how can i do it?

Comment: How are you managing your routes? Can't you just use `setTimeout` to change route to show a different screen?

Comment: i was trying but i don't know because i am new on react-native

Comment: @Endar you should update your question. I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @VojtaNovak I hope it is clear now.

Comment: It seems `Navigation` has been moved out of the react-native library. Try installing `react-navigation` and follow this example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html#react-navigation

Comment: I tried but still nothing says that Navigation is not anymore part of react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use navigation in `react-native`, the project developers recommend you use `react-navigation`. I've used it, and it works just fine. Say for example you'd like a tab bar application. You can import `TabNavigator` from `react-navigation` and use it:

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
...

const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});
```

More examples and docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab

**UPDATE:**

As there is update of react-navigation library which is v4. In v4 you can create a tab in different ways like BottomTabNavigator, MaterialBottomTabNavigator and MaterialTopTabNavigator.
So in react-navigation v4 the above code looks like this:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
...

const MyApp = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});
```

For more details docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html